# How can I backup all of my tweets?

Tags: twitter, backup

Is there a way to download a backup of all of my own tweets, in case Twitter ever goes down for good?

Comment: Note: Current twitter API limits you fetch the latest 3200 updates only, so if you have greater than 3200 updates, I doubt the services will be able to backup them.

Comment: @Sathya -- not true.  You're right that you can't get more than that *easily*, but I know for a fact that http://backupmytweets.com specifically does backup 100% of your tweets, which is actually another reason to use one of these services in the first place.

Comment: Not according to their FAQ, Jason: http://backupmy.net/faq They can only back up the most recent 3,200 tweets.

Comment: Obviously, the API only gives you access to the most recent 3200 tweets. But every tweet after you enabled the backup service, will backup the latest 3200 plus the ones you already have saved. Ie. more than 3200.

Comment: So the answer is, start backing up as soon at you start tweeting, or at least before you have > 3200 tweets. Then EVERYTHING will be backed up.

Comment: Un-Community Wikied some answers in response to a flag.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**List of Services**

- http://www.backupify.com/
- http://tweetbackup.com/
- http://backupmytweets.com/
- http://twistory.net/
- https://gimmebar.com/

**Saved to Archive**

- http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/how_to_backup_and_search_all_your_friends_tweets_i.php
- http://www.techhit.com/TwInbox/twitter_plugin_outlook.html
- http://thinkupapp.com/

**Scripts**

- http://morethanseven.net/2007/11/23/archiving-twitter-data-with-python.html (Python)
- http://www.adamfranco.com/2008/10/13/twitter-export-script/ (PHP)
- http://blog.jphpsf.com/2012/05/07/backing-up-your-twitter-account-with-t/ (Ruby)

**Self Hosted**

- http://pongsocket.com/tweetnest/

**Desktop**

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/twitter-to-pdf/

Comment: The site mentioned at http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/how_to_backup_and_search_all_your_friends_tweets_i.php no longer works.

Comment: except gimmebar, all of the other services(under list of services) have shutdown

Answer (score 10):

If you live in the EU, you can request ALL your tweets that Twitter holds on you.

Visit this link:

http://monsterswell.com/blog/2012/04/a-full-twitter-index-in-your-thinkup/

Follow these instructions (and you will need a Fax Machine):

https://www.privacyinternational.org/blog/what-does-twitter-know-about-its-users-nologs

Comment: or faxzero.com or another "free internet fax" services

Answer (score 4):

Zach Drayer ([@zadr](http://twitter.com/zadr) on Twitter) suggested filing a FOIA with the Library of Congress, if you're in the US. Haven't tried it, though.

> If I were to file a FOIA request with the Library of Congress, would I be able to get an archive of all my tweets? Cant get it from Twitter…

Source: https://twitter.com/zadr/status/199570827308580866 https://blog.twitter.com/2010/tweet-preservation

Answer (score 3):

[Twitter is starting to roll out the ability for anyone to request an archive of **all** of their tweets](http://thenextweb.com/twitter/2012/12/16/twitter-has-started-rolling-out-the-option-to-download-all-your-tweets/).

[Official Twitter blog: Your Twitter archive](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/your-twitter-archive)

Apparently it works similarly to Facebook's archive option. If the option is turned on for you, you'll see a link for "Your Twitter Archive" in Twitter Settings. Once you've made the request, and after some amount of time, an email message with a ZIP file of your Twitter messages will arrive in your inbox.

Answer (score 3):

Twitter allows its own [archive system](http://techlanes.com/2013/09/backup-your-tweets-with-twitter-archive.html) where you can request for the download. You can view its [official announcement here](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/your-twitter-archive). You can download all your tweets with no tweet limit.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your [account settings](https://twitter.com/settings/account).
2. Scroll down to **Your Tweet archive**
3. Click <kbd>**Request your archive**</kbd>
4. Wait for an email to arrive

   - Title: `It's Tweet archive time`
   - From: `notify@twitter.com`
5. Click the <kbd>**Download now**</kbd> button
6. Click the <kbd>**Download**</kbd> button in the opened page:

   [image]
7. Extract the archive in a folder, and open `index.html` with your web browser

> **Note:** Please make sure your email address is confirmed prior to requesting your Twitter archive and that you are logged into your Twitter account on the same browser you are using to download your Twitter archive.

---

<sup>Source: [How to download your Twitter archive](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/how-to-download-your-twitter-archive)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [SocialSafe](http://socialsafe.net/networks/twitter) to backup the content of your Twitter account. Again, it is restricted by the API limit of the most recent 3,200 tweets when you start backing up, but as others have said, the sooner the start backing up the less you'll miss. All of the content is stored on your own PC/Mac, so you aren't sharing your data with anyone.

SocialSafe backs up the following:

- Tweets
- Mentions
- DMs
- Favourites
- Followers
- Following
- Profile information

There is a free trial available that allows you full usage of SocialSafe, which also includes the capability of exporting to CSV. You can download the PC/Mac installer from the [SocialSafe website](http://socialsafe.net).

Hope this helps.