# Where can I search for existing archives of Twitter searches?

Tags: twitter

I know there are several Twitter archiving services, such as [Twapperkeeper](http://twapperkeeper.com/). That's the only one that I can find that has public archives of searches. However, it lacks the search I want, namely [#palinemails](https://twitter.com/#!/search?q=%23palinemails).

Where else could I look to generate an archive of tweets with that or any hashtag more than two weeks old?

Comment: Not really an archive but you can just use Google search `site:twitter.com inurl:status +palinemails`

Comment: That is a really good suggestion. It looks like I need to apply for an API key for the search APIs for Google, Bing, and Yahoo so maybe screen scrapping is more appropriate for an adhoc endeavor.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, you can use Google search `site:twitter.com inurl:status +palinemails`. There isn't a canonical resource that holds all Twitter archives publicly. Try checking this related question to see if it can assist you in searching for other tweets labelled with `#palinemails`.

[How can I backup all of my tweets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/657/how-can-i-backup-all-of-my-tweets)