# Archive all Twitter messages for an account

Tags: twitter

I would like to archive a list of all tweets for a specific account, preferably in PDF.

Does anyone know if this is possible on Twitter?

Comment: Related http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/657/how-can-i-backup-all-of-my-tweets

Comment: Is this an account you own, or just a random account?

Comment: @ChrisF random account, not mine

Comment: @phwd As writen above to ChrisF, that question is about backing up *your own* tweets and my question is about *other peoples* tweets so it's a distinction and although the solution maybe is the same, it's not a duplicate IMHO.

Comment: Okay it's reopened though I don't know how this changes anything, I wouldn't be surprised if any further solution other than the 3200 API limit call becomes available that isn't already repeated on the other question. This is being split on semantics of any user versus current user which in terms of the Twitter API comes down to just *a user* but yeah, your question is reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site [All My Tweets](http://www.allmytweets.net/) is a very easy way to display up to 3200 tweets for a single user. It works by using the Javascript API to fetch tweets and display them inline on a single page, which you can then save as HTML, print to PDF, or print to paper.

Comment: A lot has changed since I answered this. Twitter now provides an archive download of all tweets. I also wrote a sort of enhanced version of AllMyTweets, although its dependency on the Twitter API means it may not last long. It's at http://www.somebits.com/tweetchive/

Answer (score 2):

The Twitter API only allows you to retrieve the latest 3,200 tweets for any user. But here's how you can do that assuming the account has less than 3,200 tweets.  Also, you can only get 200 at a time.

You can use: `http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?id=<username>&count=200&max_id=`

Once you have the first page grab the id of the last tweet listed and throw it in the `max_id` parameter to get the next 200.

Twitter does have pages for tweets, but that variable is being deprecated on May 14, 2012.

Comment: You will be subject to api call limitations: According to Twitter's [rate limiting](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting) guidelines the following are the limits: Authenticated: 350/hour, Unauthenticated: 150/hour.

Comment: it's 3200 tweets for all - be it authenticated or unauthenticated user

Comment: That's a good point. Updating answer